# Get size of Regex.MatchIterator in Scala 2.7.7?

Tags: regex, scala, iterator

What is the most elegant way to get the size of a `Regex.MatchIterator` in Scala 2.7.7?

I tried the following:

```
¤ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.7.7final (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> "a".r.findAllIn("a").size  
<console>:5: error: value size is not a member of scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator
       "a".r.findAllIn("a").size
                            ^

scala> "a".r.findAllIn("a").size()
<console>:5: error: value size is not a member of scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator
       "a".r.findAllIn("a").size()
                            ^
```

Comment: I don't have Scala 2.7.7, but your example works in later Scala versions. Did you try `length`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `length` as well:
`scala> "a".r.findAllIn("a").length`
`<console>:5: error: value length is not a member of scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the Iterator:

```
iter.toList.size
```

Be sure to save the converted iterator (if you want to access the data after calculating the size) because it can only iterated once.

Instead of converting to another collection you can also use foldLeft:

```
(0 /: iter) { case (sum, _) => sum+1 }
```